# SQL query ... select records that shown only one time , and ignore more that 2 times

Tags: sql

I have table like below

[image]

I want to select only TV-Samsung because it is shown only one time in table and ignore others because shown more than one time
I tried this query but not working

```
select item_id, barcode, qty
from table
where barcode NOT IN (SELECT barcode FROM table
                      GROUP BY barcode HAVING Count(barcode) > 1)
```

best regards

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS you use. What does "not working" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Syntax works for me.

Comment: Use the below query to get the records.

``

SELECT item_id, barcode, qty
FROM table1
WHERE barcode NOT IN (
    SELECT barcode
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY barcode
    HAVING COUNT(barcode) > 1
);

``

Comment: Your query works as far as I can see. https://dbfiddle.uk/x7ZuyT3_

Comment: BTW, poor table design. Don't store the same item_id/barcode combination several times.

Comment: The best (and even correct) answer heavily depends on your RDBMS and version, the exact table definition (what's unique? what's NOT NULL? ...) and cardinalities (total row count, avg dupe count). From your data sample I *guess* `barcode` shall be unique, and `item_id` is just noise for the purpose - and just has a misleading name. But just provide proper info, then there is no need to guess.

Answer (score 3):

To select the rows for which no other row with the same item_id exists:

```
select  *
from    table
where   item_id in
        (
        select  item_id
        from    table
        group by
                item_id
        having  count(*) = 1
        )
```

Comment: OP's original SQL should work - does for me. This version should produce same result. Don't think have enough info to resolve.